# Removing a wrapper function callback with removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, callback, event-listener

I have this code, which drags a ball around a canvas on click and drag.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  var initialClickX = mouse.x;
  var initialClickY = mouse.y;
  var initialBallX = ball.x;
  var initialBallY = ball.y;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
      onMouseMove(initialClickX, initialClickY, mouse.x, mouse.y, initialBallX, initialBallY)
  }, false);

}, false);

function onMouseMove(initialClickX, initialClickY, mouseX, mouseY, initialBallX,     initialBallY){
    ball.x = mouseX + initialBallX - initialClickX;
    ball.y = mouseY + initialBallY - initialClickY;
    draw();
}
```

The trouble is, I can't get the ball to stop dragging when I mouseup. I know that I need to add:

```
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', function() {
      onMouseMove(initialClickX, initialClickY, mouse.x, mouse.y, initialBallX, initialBallY)
  }, false);
```

But because the function is in a wrapper the above has no effect and the ball remains stuck to my cursor. Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: Make an actual named function, that contains your listener's code. Then use `canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", functionReference, false);` and later `canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", functionReference);`. So you'd have something like `var functionReference = function () { onMouseMove(initialClickX, initialClickY, mouse.x, mouse.y, initialBallX, initialBallY); };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an anonymous function. You need to hold a reference to the event listener function for later removal.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  var initialClickX = mouse.x;
  var initialClickY = mouse.y;
  var initialBallX = ball.x;
  var initialBallY = ball.y;

  function wrapper() {
      onMouseMove(initialClickX, initialClickY, mouse.x, mouse.y, initialBallX, initialBallY)
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', wrapper, false);

  // some time later
  canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', wrapper);

}, false);
```